# Rolling computation of two simultaneous variables iteratively or rowwise, using three other given variables

Tags: r, dplyr, iteration, rolling-computation, accumulate

The dataset named `crass` looks like -

```
> dput(crass)
structure(list(WT_TRADE_PRICE = c(3801, 3801, 3801, 3797, 3797, 
3796.2125, 3800, 3797, 3795.09523809524, 3794, 3793, 3793, 3793.8, 
3794.72, 3793.02777777778, 3789, 3790, 3788, 3788, 3788), min = c(3801, 
3801, 3801, 3797, 3797, 3795, 3800, 3797, 3794, 3794, 3793, 3793, 
3793, 3794, 3790, 3789, 3790, 3788, 3788, 3788), max = c(3801, 
3801, 3801, 3797, 3797, 3800, 3800, 3797, 3797, 3794, 3793, 3793, 
3794, 3797, 3794, 3789, 3790, 3788, 3788, 3788), Bid = c(3801, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Ask = c(3802, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
   WT_TRADE_PRICE   min   max   Bid   Ask
            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1          3801   3801  3801  3801  3802
 2          3801   3801  3801    NA    NA
 3          3801   3801  3801    NA    NA
 4          3797   3797  3797    NA    NA
 5          3797   3797  3797    NA    NA
 6          3796.  3795  3800    NA    NA
 7          3800   3800  3800    NA    NA
 8          3797   3797  3797    NA    NA
 9          3795.  3794  3797    NA    NA
10          3794   3794  3794    NA    NA
11          3793   3793  3793    NA    NA
12          3793   3793  3793    NA    NA
13          3794.  3793  3794    NA    NA
14          3795.  3794  3797    NA    NA
15          3793.  3790  3794    NA    NA
16          3789   3789  3789    NA    NA
17          3790   3790  3790    NA    NA
18          3788   3788  3788    NA    NA
19          3788   3788  3788    NA    NA
20          3788   3788  3788    NA    NA
```

As can be seen, two variables `ask` & `bid` have only initial values which need to be filled iteratively using the following logic.

- If `WT_TRDAE_PRICE` is `>=` than previous value of `Ask`  **OR** `WT_TRADE_PRICE` will be checked whether `>` than mean of previous `bid` and `ask` - then current `ask` will be set equal to current row `max` variable and `bid` will be set equal to previous `bid` value.
- Else , current `ask` will be set to previous `ask` value & `bid` to `max`.

Pseudo code -

```
if(WT_TRADE_PRICE >= L(Ask) | WT_TRADE_PRICE > (L(Bid)+L(Ask))/2)
{
  Bid = L(Bid), Ask = max
}
else
{
  Bid = min, Ask = L(Ask)
}
```

Final output -

| SNo. | WT_TRADE_PRICE | min | max | Bid | Ask |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3801 | 3801 | 3801 | 3801 | 3802 |
| 2 | 3801 | 3801 | 3801 | 3801 | 3802 |
| 3 | 3801 | 3801 | 3801 | 3801 | 3802 |
| 4 | 3797 | 3797 | 3797 | 3797 | 3802 |
| 5 | 3797 | 3797 | 3797 | 3797 | 3802 |
| 6 | 3796. | 3795 | 3800 | 3795 | 3802 |
| 7 | 3800 | 3800 | 3800 | 3795 | 3800 |
| 8 | 3797 | 3797 | 3797 | 3797 | 3800 |
| 9 | 3795. | 3794 | 3797 | 3794 | 3800 |
| 10 | 3794 | 3794 | 3794 | 3794 | 3800 |
| 11 | 3793 | 3793 | 3793 | 3793 | 3800 |
| 12 | 3793 | 3793 | 3793 | 3793 | 3800 |
| 13 | 3794. | 3793 | 3794 | 3793 | 3800 |
| 14 | 3795. | 3794 | 3797 | 3793 | 3797 |
| 15 | 3793. | 3790 | 3794 | 3790 | 3797 |
| 16 | 3789 | 3789 | 3789 | 3789 | 3797 |
| 17 | 3790 | 3790 | 3790 | 3790 | 3797 |
| 18 | 3788 | 3788 | 3788 | 3788 | 3797 |
| 19 | 3788 | 3788 | 3788 | 3788 | 3797 |
| 20 | 3788 | 3788 | 3788 | 3788 | 3797 |

Comment: I think your input dput and table input values are different.  Can you please correct

Comment: `crass %>% mutate(Bid = min, Prev_Bid = lag(Bid))` this gives the expected output.  May be a better example would make it more clear

Comment: Simplified your condition

Comment: @akrun, In your leisure time please see this question.  Since `accumulate2` can handle at most two variables, I converted three variables to one row tibble each and used `accumulate` to generate two simultaneous variables.  But I am sure you can provide some alternate strategy in these cases where more than 2 variables need to be passed into `accumulate` since we do not have `paccumulate` kinda thing

Comment: @AnilGoyal I would use `for` loop as it have greater flexibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case, we require to generate two output columns simultaneously; and iteratively with the help of three inputs.  So `purrr::accumulate` normally works on one output based on one input, whereas `purrr::accumulate2()` works on 2 inputs for again one output.  So instead, my strategy for `accumulate` is as under:-

- Re-arrange three input columns into row-wise tibbles each, so that each of three columns inputs are now a single column.  For this, I generated a dummy column `id` so that each row is converted to a tibble each.
- I used `tidyr::nest_by()` for this
- again for output I generated a tibble instead of a vector through accumulate.
- Lastly I converted both tibbles back to their original shapes by using `tidyr::unnnest_wider()`

```
crass[1:3] %>% 
  nest_by(id = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(new = accumulate(data, 
                          .init = list(Bid = 3801, Ask = 3802),
                          ~ tibble(Bid = ifelse(.y$WT_TRADE_PRICE >= min(.x$Ask, (.x$Ask + .x$Bid)/2),
                                                     .x$Bid,
                                                     .y$min),
                                        Ask = ifelse(.y$WT_TRADE_PRICE >= min(.x$Ask, (.x$Ask + .x$Bid)/2),
                                                     .y$max,
                                                     .x$Ask))
                          )[-1]) %>%
  unnest_wider(data) %>%
  unnest_wider(new)

# A tibble: 20 x 6
      id WT_TRADE_PRICE   min   max   Bid   Ask
   <int>          <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1          3801   3801  3801  3801  3802
 2     2          3801   3801  3801  3801  3802
 3     3          3801   3801  3801  3801  3802
 4     4          3797   3797  3797  3797  3802
 5     5          3797   3797  3797  3797  3802
 6     6          3796.  3795  3800  3795  3802
 7     7          3800   3800  3800  3795  3800
 8     8          3797   3797  3797  3797  3800
 9     9          3795.  3794  3797  3794  3800
10    10          3794   3794  3794  3794  3800
11    11          3793   3793  3793  3793  3800
12    12          3793   3793  3793  3793  3800
13    13          3794.  3793  3794  3793  3800
14    14          3795.  3794  3797  3794  3800
15    15          3793.  3790  3794  3790  3800
16    16          3789   3789  3789  3789  3800
17    17          3790   3790  3790  3790  3800
18    18          3788   3788  3788  3788  3800
19    19          3788   3788  3788  3788  3800
20    20          3788   3788  3788  3788  3800
```

**Earlier Revised for loop**

#### Syntax

```
for(i in 2:nrow(crass)){
    if(crass[i, 1] >= min(crass[i-1, 5], (crass[i-1, 4] + crass[i-1, 5])/2)){
    crass[i, 5] <- crass[i, 3]
    crass[i, 4] <- crass[i-1, 4]
  } else {
    crass[i, 4] <- crass[i, 2]
    crass[i, 5] <- crass[i-1, 5]
  } 
}

crass
# A tibble: 20 x 5
   WT_TRADE_PRICE   min   max   Bid   Ask
            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1          3801   3801  3801  3801  3802
 2          3801   3801  3801  3801  3802
 3          3801   3801  3801  3801  3802
 4          3797   3797  3797  3797  3802
 5          3797   3797  3797  3797  3802
 6          3796.  3795  3800  3795  3802
 7          3800   3800  3800  3795  3800
 8          3797   3797  3797  3797  3800
 9          3795.  3794  3797  3794  3800
10          3794   3794  3794  3794  3800
11          3793   3793  3793  3793  3800
12          3793   3793  3793  3793  3800
13          3794.  3793  3794  3793  3800
14          3795.  3794  3797  3794  3800
15          3793.  3790  3794  3790  3800
16          3789   3789  3789  3789  3800
17          3790   3790  3790  3790  3800
18          3788   3788  3788  3788  3800
19          3788   3788  3788  3788  3800
20          3788   3788  3788  3788  3800
```

`crass` before running of for loop

```
# A tibble: 20 x 5
   WT_TRADE_PRICE   min   max   Bid   Ask
            <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1          3801   3801  3801  3801  3802
 2          3801   3801  3801    NA    NA
 3          3801   3801  3801    NA    NA
 4          3797   3797  3797    NA    NA
 5          3797   3797  3797    NA    NA
 6          3796.  3795  3800    NA    NA
 7          3800   3800  3800    NA    NA
 8          3797   3797  3797    NA    NA
 9          3795.  3794  3797    NA    NA
10          3794   3794  3794    NA    NA
11          3793   3793  3793    NA    NA
12          3793   3793  3793    NA    NA
13          3794.  3793  3794    NA    NA
14          3795.  3794  3797    NA    NA
15          3793.  3790  3794    NA    NA
16          3789   3789  3789    NA    NA
17          3790   3790  3790    NA    NA
18          3788   3788  3788    NA    NA
19          3788   3788  3788    NA    NA
20          3788   3788  3788    NA    NA
```

Comment: On row 13, wt_trade_price = 3794 which is greater than L(Bid) ~ 3793. also wt_trade_price <(L(bid) + L(ask))/2 = 3796.5. So it works for the fourth conditional.

Comment: Minor correction done in loop.  Still I can see some problem in row 14.  WT (3795) is > L(Bid) i.e. 3793 and lower than mean of 3973 & 3800 (3796.5), then row-14 Bid should be 3794 & ask should be 3800.  Please re-check

Comment: This process is fine but this is too slow - the dataset has 3 million rows. Any vectorized solutions?

Comment: @shoonya, have you checked the vectorised solution

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the following solution in base R.
For this solution I used row numbers as the primary vector to be used in `Reduce`. We can use this technique where we have more than one output variables. It should be noted that for differentiating between the previous value of `Bid` and `Ask` I used double brackets to subset the required value.

```
cbind(crass[1:3], 
      do.call(rbind, Reduce(function(x, y) {
        data.frame(Bid = ifelse(crass$WT_TRADE_PRICE[y] >= min(x[["Ask"]], (x[["Ask"]] + x[["Bid"]])/2),
                                x[["Bid"]],
                                crass$min[y]),
                   Ask = ifelse(crass$WT_TRADE_PRICE[y] >= min(x[["Ask"]], (x[["Ask"]] + x[["Bid"]])/2),
                                crass$max[y],
                                x[["Ask"]]))
      }, init = data.frame(Bid = crass$Bid[1],
                           Ask = crass$Ask[1]),
      seq_len(nrow(crass))[-1], accumulate = TRUE)))
```

**Result**

```
   WT_TRADE_PRICE  min  max  Bid  Ask
1        3801.000 3801 3801 3801 3802
2        3801.000 3801 3801 3801 3802
3        3801.000 3801 3801 3801 3802
4        3797.000 3797 3797 3797 3802
5        3797.000 3797 3797 3797 3802
6        3796.213 3795 3800 3795 3802
7        3800.000 3800 3800 3795 3800
8        3797.000 3797 3797 3797 3800
9        3795.095 3794 3797 3794 3800
10       3794.000 3794 3794 3794 3800
11       3793.000 3793 3793 3793 3800
12       3793.000 3793 3793 3793 3800
13       3793.800 3793 3794 3793 3800
14       3794.720 3794 3797 3794 3800
15       3793.028 3790 3794 3790 3800
16       3789.000 3789 3789 3789 3800
17       3790.000 3790 3790 3790 3800
18       3788.000 3788 3788 3788 3800
19       3788.000 3788 3788 3788 3800
20       3788.000 3788 3788 3788 3800
```